# Get intersections of all linestrings within a GeoDataFrame (geopandas) in python

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame containing some streets of a city (every row is a linestring). I would like to obtain another GeoDataFrame with all the intersections between those streets (as Points). All I can see is how to intersect 2 different GeoDataFrames. Is there any way to do it other than looping over the streets and intersecting with the rest?
Thanks!

Comment: If anybody is interested, found the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137909/intersecting-lines-get-crossings